# How to use point column type in Ecto using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I can see that `Postgrex` lib supports postgreSQL's `point` type but I can't figure out how I can use it in model. I can specify `point` type for column in migration but when I specify it in the model like this:

```
schema "something" do
  field :position, :point
end
```

I get `** (ArgumentError) invalid or unknown type :point for field :position`. Anything special I should do to make it work?

Comment: I think you'll need to use a third party library like [geo](https://github.com/bryanjos/geo) for this. `Geo.Point` in that library for example implements the Ecto.Type behavior: https://github.com/bryanjos/geo/blob/master/lib/geo/point.ex.

Comment: @Dogbert I think you should post this as an answer.

Comment: yeah, @Dogbert feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ecto does not contain any `Ecto.Type` implementing module for the `point` data type in PostgreSQL. You can either define your own module with `Ecto.Type` behavior for it or use a library like [`geo`](https://github.com/bryanjos/geo) which includes [`Geo.Point`](https://github.com/bryanjos/geo/blob/master/lib/geo/point.ex) which [implements the `Ecto.Type` behavior](https://github.com/bryanjos/geo/blob/20b2c0ab06554aca455e14b42b8c094d2fa82084/lib/geo/point.ex#L10).

With `geo`, your schema would look something like:

```
schema "something" do
  field :position, Geo.Point
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `geo` library has moved all Ecto-related code to a separate library [(see related pull request here)](https://github.com/bryanjos/geo/pull/88).

To use the `Ecto.Type` implementation of PostgreSQL `point` datatype, use the [`geo_postgis`](https://github.com/bryanjos/geo_postgis) library.